# Values are not getting entered into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

Hi am developing a project in java and am using netbeans for that. I have a code to connect to the database. It is working, but values are not getting entered into the database. I will provide the code below. I have 2 classes and the first one is below :

```
package javasql;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect {
public Connect() throws SQLException{
    makeConnection();
} 

private Connection koneksi;  

 public  Connection makeConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (koneksi == null) {
         new Driver();
        // buat koneksi
         koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","virus");
     }
     return koneksi;
 }  

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     try {
         Connect c = new Connect();
         System.out.println("Connection established");
     }
     catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("Connection Failure");
     }  

}
}
```

The second class is this:

```
package javasql;

import java.sql.*;
public class SqlStatement {
private Statement statement;
public SqlStatement() throws SQLException{

}
public Statement makeStatement() throws SQLException{
    Connect c = new Connect();
    Connection conn = c.makeConnection();
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    return statement;
}
public void insert(String name,int npm)throws SQLException{
    statement.execute("insert into student values(\""+name+"\","+npm+");");
}
public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException{
    SqlStatement sss;
    sss = new SqlStatement();
    sss.makeStatement();
    try {
        SqlStatement s = new SqlStatement();
        s.insert("Ferdi",1);
        s.insert("Anca",2);
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This throws a NullPointerException, right? The stack trace should explain you why. Your code is messy: you create objects twice for no reason, ignore returned values, don't use prepared statements.

Comment: @JBNizet Really sorry...The 3 lines of code after public static void main is not actually in my code..I just forget to correct it. This program don't gave any exceptions. when I ran it, I got "Connection established" in netbeans. But the values were not entered in the database.

Comment: You executed the Connect class, which does nothing other than connecting to the database. Execute the other class, which tries to insert rows to the database, and you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @JBNizet yes...SQLException came. What to do now ?

Comment: Read the message of the exception and its stack trace. Understand what it means. Deduce what needs to be changed in the code.

Comment: @JBNizet No database selected error is shown. Why is it showing ? Is my DriverManager.getConnection() wrong ?

Comment: @TomJ `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"` theres no database stated

Comment: Google is your best friend. Click http://tinyurl.com/nu2sezp
 and click on the first returned link.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks bro..Finally you helped me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have missed to provide `database` name to establish the connection.The format to connect with `mysql` is :

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

But in the provided code the `dbname` is missing due to which you was failing to connect with DB.

Please provide the `dbname` and move ahead.

Comment: @TomJ grtt move ahead dear

Answer (score 0):

Execute `s.makeStatement()` before `s.insert()`
Your code is quite... messy.